# How to change the active navbar icon on navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a javascript code to change the highlighted item on the menu based on the url accessed, but I'm novice with javascript. After some research I ended up with the code below:

```js
const currentLocation = location.href;
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const menuLenght = menuItem.length
for (let i = 0; i < menuLenght; i++) {
  if menuItem[i].href === currentLocation {
    menuItem[i].className = "active"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active megamenu">
      <a href="/index.php" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="megamenu"><a href="/institution">institution</a></li>

    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </li>
</div>
```

After saving and testing it didn't give me the expected result, but I can't determine why. Could anybody tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: `Let` should have a lowercase `l`

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the current location first ,try this :

```
  const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
      const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      const menuLenght = menuItem.length
      let current_location="/"+window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1]
      for (let i = 0; i < menuLenght; i++) {
        if (menuItem[i].href === current_location) {
        menuItem[i].className = "active"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong?,
as per the code given by you ,your active class should be applied to `<li>` not to `<a>`
first you should select all `<li>` using class name

`const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu');`

this class 'megamenu' should be applied to all `<li>`, consider the last `<li>`.
after that you should find out `<a>` from `<li>` which is the very first node of it,
and check for the href value, if its match with current url ,active class should be added to `<li>` not to `<a>`

```
for (let i = 0; i < menuLenght; i++) {
    if menuItem[i].children[0].href === currentLocation {
    menuItem[i].className = "megamenu active";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way:

On the `a` tag, you can add a `onclick` handler and in the function, you can add the class. When you add the `onclick` handler, pass the event. With this, you can add styles, classes etc.,

Also, if you want to highlight the link, add the `active` class to the `<a>` not `<li>`

Code:

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> 
         How to get values from html input 
         array using JavaScript ? 
      </title>
      <style>
         .active{
         color: red;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body style="text-align: center;">
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="megamenu">
               <a href="/index.php" class="dropdown-toggle active" onclick="changeColor(event)">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="megamenu">
               <a href="/institution" onclick="changeColor(event)">institution</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="/contact" onclick="changeColor(event)">Contact</a>        
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function changeColor(e){
             e.currentTarget.className = "active";
         }
         
         
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```